# create-react-app not working. Getting error "Module not found"

Tags: reactjs

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSK8S.png)

I am not able to create a project using create-react-app, I get the error "Module not found".

Node version is 17.0.1 and Npm version is 8.1.1

I have reinstalled nodejs 3 times now and have tried different commands like

```
npm install create-react-app -g

npm cache clean --force
```

P.S - I have updated the nodejs to 17.0.1 as the picture version shows 16.13.0

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started ? They recommend not installing globally, but use `npx` . Also, you have to create an app using `create-react-app my-cool-app`

Comment: Yeah I did the same, uninstalled the create-react-app globally then tried with npx but its still showing error.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your install location. You create the app on desktop, but it's looking in a different folder for the module. As far as I understand, when you work locally (instead of having global installs), everything has to exist inside the same folder.

Comment: You might need to uninstall the global variant first using `npm uninstall create-react-app -g`

Comment: Did it. Still getting the same issue :(

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `npx create-react-app my-app`.

Visit for more details [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/)

To create a new app, you may choose one of the following methods:

**npx**

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

**npm**

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

`npm init <initializer>` *is available in npm 6+*

**Yarn**

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

`yarn create` *is available in Yarn 0.25+*

Comment: Still getting the same error. "Module not found". 
Stuck at this for 2-3 hours :(

Answer (score 1):

So after almost 3-4 hours of trying different things, it has worked.
I dont know which particular thing would have helped it to work but following are the things I tried -

- Delete npm and npm cache folder.
- Reinstall the nodejs (LTS version).
- Create the app in another folder.
- Used power shell instead of CMD.
- `npm fix`
- `npm fix --force`